# What's the best way to avoid naming conflict in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

It appears that the when multiple modules have factories with the same name, the last one wins. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRr8r/4/)

I've seen posts suggesting the conventions for naming the factories with `fooBar`, `foo2Bar` or `foo.bar` `foo2.bar` to avoid naming conflicts

However, prefixing each factory with module name seems pretty ugly to me.  Is there any other better way, or is there any way to have private services that's only local to the module?

Answer (score 1):

You don't like foobar? Seems like a pretty good convention to me.
However you can 'namespace' your javascript code if you'd like. 
http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/